# Java FileWriter outputs a question mark

Tags: java, filewriter

I have been unable to find the reason for this. The only problem I am having in this code is that when the `FileWriter` tries to put the new value into the text file, it instead puts a ?. I have no clue why, or even what it means. Here is the code:

```
if (secMessage[1].equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
    if (secMessage.length==2) {
        try {
            String deaths = readFile("C:/Users/Samboni/Documents/Stuff For Streaming/deaths.txt", Charset.defaultCharset());
            FileWriter write = new FileWriter("C:/Users/Samboni/Documents/Stuff For Streaming/deaths.txt");
            int comb = Integer.parseInt(deaths) + 1;
            write.write(comb);
            write.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the readFile method:

```
static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) throws IOException {
    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
    return new String(encoded, encoding);
}
```

Also, the secMessage array is an array of strings containing the words of an IRC message split into individual words, that way the program can react to the commands on a word-by-word basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling [`Writer.write(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write-int-). That writes a single UTF-16 code point to the file, taking just the bottom 16 bits. If your platform default encoding isn't able to represent the code point you're trying to write, it will write '?' as a replacement character.

I suspect you *actually* want to write out a text representation of the number, in which case you should use:

```
write.write(String.valueOf(comb));
```

In other words, turn the value into a string and *then* write it out. So if `comb` is 123, you'll get three characters ('1', '2', '3') written to the file.

Personally I'd avoid `FileWriter` though - I prefer using `OutputStreamWriter` wrapping `FileOutputStream` so you can control the encoding. Or in Java 7, you can use `Files.newBufferedWriter` to do it more simply.

Comment: This worked very well. I didn't realize I had to have it write it as a string. Also, might I ask what the purpose of controlling the encoding would be?

Comment: To complete with a clue: The question mark would be the *substitution sequence* the Writer uses whenever it is given something to write that can't be written.

Comment: @Samboni: Well if you don't specify the encoding, it will use the platform default - which isn't necessarily what you want. (If you later transfer the file to a different system, that could cause problems.) For files which are just ASCII it's less of a problem, but I think it's worth being explicit - and usually using UTF-8 if you get to choose.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah ok. Makes sense then. So it's mainly an issue of if I know for a fact the file will never leave my system, it's fine, but if there's even a chance of it going somewhere else, I want to choose encoding?

Comment: @Samboni: I think it's a good idea to *always* specify the encoding - even if you deliberately use the platform default encoding, it makes your code really clear if you do that explicitly. But personally I'd almost always just use UTF-8 explicitly. I very rarely see a benefit in using the platform default.

Comment: @JonSkeet Alright, I'll keep that in mind then. Will probably make it easier for the future questions I will probably be asking here at some point...

Answer (score 0):

```
write.write(new Integer(comb).toString());
```

You can convert the int into a string. Otherwise you will need the int to be a character. That will only work for a small subset of numbers, 0-9, so it is not recommended.